# iOS Keyboard Active but Invisible when UISearchBar is tapped

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, keyboard, uisearchbar

I have an issue which performs exactly as depicted here.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fup-WrgN3wA
I am not the owner of this video and am unable to find any meaningful solutions to the issue depicted in it.

Im my case: I have a UITableView with a UISearchBar in it. Tapping the UISearchBar makes it the firstResponder with a blinking cursor ready to accept keyboard inputs. However the Keyboard is invisible but still clickable.

If I leave it in that state for 10-20 seconds, the keyboard magically appears on its own without any reason.

Has anyone experienced this and what was done to resolve it?

I have tried UISearchBar/UISearchBar and Search Display/UITextField - with same results on all.

Latest iOS 8.1.2
Latest Xcode 6.1.1

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you are working with simulator try, go to Hardware->Keyboard->Toggle Software Keyboard or CMD+K. Sometimes it is turned off without any reason.

Comment: Hi Bejibun, Thanks for your reply. I have checked and thats not the cause. And it also occurs on the Device iPhone 6.

Comment: Figured it out: It was linked to the VC from which the current VC was being segued into. And the previous VC was incorrectly and temporarily blocking the main ui thread.