# Keyboard and UIBarButtonItem working but invisible

Tags: ios, keyboard, segue, uibarbuttonitem, hierarchy

I have a ViewController that is presenting a TableViewController modally

Hierarchy:

`ViewController A =modalSegue=> NavigationController => TableViewController`

Now there are 2 problems:

1. The BarbuttonItem in my TableViewController is not shown, but working (I can click on it, which brings me to another ViewController B with a push segue)
2. Within this ViewController B, I have a TextField and when you click on it, the cursor appears, but the Keyboard keeps invisible. Yet I can still use it (press the buttons, which appear in the TextField).

The thing is that if I change the InitialViewController arrow to the TableViewController, everything works fine. If it helps, I am doing a TouchID-Verification in ViewController A and if this is successful, the TableViewController is presented modally.

I have searched for answers in several forums already, but the only thing I found was this (which could be a similar issue): [iOS Keyboard Active but Invisible when UISearchBar is tapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513103/ios-keyboard-active-but-invisible-when-uisearchbar-is-tapped/28155351#28155351)
The question-asker solved the issue by himself but he did not provide any solution. In addition, I did not really understand his comment.

So would you be so nice and help me with these two issues ?
Thank you !